# Java producer/consumer, detecting end of processing

Tags: java, queue, task, producer-consumer

I'm preparing an application where a single producer generates several million tasks, which will then be processed by a configurable number of consumers. Communication from producer to consumer is (probably) going to be queue-based.

From the thread that runs the producer/generates the tasks, what method can I use to wait for completion of all tasks? I'd rather not resume to any periodic polling to see if my tasks queue is empty. In any case, the task queue being empty isn't actually a guarantee that the last tasks have completed. Those tasks can be relatively long-running, so it's quite possible that the queue is empty while the consumer threads are still happily processing.

Rgds, Maarten

Answer (score 3):

You might want to have a look at the java.util.concurrent package.

- [ExecutorService](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html)
- [Executors](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html)
- [Future](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html)

The executor framework already provides means to execute tasks via threadpool. The `Future` abstraction allows to wait for the completition of tasks.

Putting both together allows you coordinate the executions easily, decoupling tasks, activities (threads) and results.

Example:

```
    ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(16);

    List<Callable<Void>> tasks = null;
    //TODO: fill tasks;

    //dispatch 
    List<Future<Void>> results =  executorService.invokeAll(tasks);

    //Wait until all tasks have completed
    for(Future<Void> result: results){
        result.get();
    }
```

**Edit: Alternative Version using `CountDownLatch`**

```
    ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(16);

    final CountDownLatch latch;

    List<Callable<Void>> tasks = null;
    //TODO: fill tasks;

    latch = new CountDownLatch(tasks.size());

    //dispatch 
    executorService.invokeAll(tasks);

    //Wait until all tasks have completed
    latch.await();
```

And inside your tasks:

```
    Callable<Void> task = new Callable<Void>()
    {

        @Override
        public Void call() throws Exception
        {
            // TODO: do your stuff

            latch.countDown(); //<---- important part
            return null;
        }
    };
```

Comment: Yes, was planning to use Executors anyways already. However, unless I misunderstand Futures, I don't think I can use them. I can have several million tasks, which would mean having to track several million Futures **in memory**. Don't really want to do that...

Comment: You could also use a `CountDownLatch`, I've added another example.

Comment: Oh, I like the idea of a CountDownLatch, except that I don't know the number of tasks beforehand, and I can't first generate the full list of tasks because it wouldn't fit in the available JVM heap... Is there any alternative to a CountDownLatch, basically some reference count tracker, where I could do "refcount++" when adding a task and "refcount--" when completing a task?

Comment: OK, so it's a bit more complex when you don't know the task count apriori. So you might want to implement your own CountDownLatch where you can also increment. You must also add another method with activates the real barrier. This is needed in the moment you dispatched your very last task. Otherwise the Latch might break due to premature drain. Implementation should be easy using `AtomicInteger`, a volatile boolean and an internal `CountDownLatch(1)`, perhaps even `AbstractQueuedSynchronizer`.

Comment: I think I'm going to try to use something like the CountUpDownLatch as posted on http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0120__Development/CountUpDownLatch.htm. Except that I think that that example needs a few "synchronized" and "volatile" in order to make it fully thread-safe

Comment: Yes, you should do this. Definitely not looking thread-safe so far.

Answer (score 1):

You want to know where every tasks completes. I would have another queue of completed task reports. (One object/message per task) When this count reaches the number of tasks you created, they have all completed. This task report can also have any errors and timing information for the task.

Comment: Hmmm, interesting idea. This would require an extra thread that reads the Report Queue. That report thread could then notify the producer thread on some monitor object.

Answer (score 1):

You could have each consumer check to see if the queue is empty when they dequeue, and, if it is, pulse a condvar (or a Monitor, since I believe that's what Java has) on which the main thread is waiting.

Having the threads check a global boolean variable (marked as volatile) is a way to let the threads know that they should stop.

Comment: That tells you every task has dequed rather than each task has completed.

Comment: Which is why having a global variable that you can use to tell the threads to stop themselves and then join them is the suggestion of the second paragraph.

Answer (score 0):

You can use join() method for each thread ..so that till all the threads are done your main thread will not end! And by this way you can actually find out whether all the threads are done or not!